# VBA Code to Autofill a Column Based on values from a different column

Tags: excel, vba

In Column E i have numbers and NA. For all NA in column E, I have to Autofill Column D with "create/map". can someone help me in fixing my code? Thanks.

```
Sub Rules1()
'
'Autofill based on Rules
'

'
    Worksheets("ORD_CS").Activate
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
LR = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With sht
        For i = 8 To LR
            If Range("H" & i).Value = "NA" Then
                Range("D" & i).Value = "Create/Map"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

End Sub

Comment: what is the problem? do you have errors or it does not do what it should? also, if you are using `with` you should prepend your `Range` with a dot: `.Range`

Comment: @avb - I got It. Was referring some other column in the code. Thank you so much for looking through my code and replying back. Appreciate it!